Using a OncePerRequestFilter to implement custom authentication causes spring to map all exceptions to 403
Here's my code
package com.fnot.backend.config.spring.security

import com.fnot.backend.config.external.telegram.TelegramConfig
import com.fnot.backend.domain.external.telegram.bot.service.TelegramBotService
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter

@Component
class TelegramAuthenticationFilter(
    telegramConfig: TelegramConfig,
    private val telegramBotService: TelegramBotService
): OncePerRequestFilter() {

    private val botToken = telegramConfig.botToken

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val authHeader = request.getHeader("TG-Authorization")
        if(authHeader == null)  {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            return
        }

        val tmaAuthData = TmaAuthData(authHeader, botToken)

        if (tmaAuthData.isValid()) {
            val telegramUserData = tmaAuthData.getTelegramUserData()
            val user = telegramBotService.registerOrUpdateUserTma(telegramUserData)

            val authToken = TelegramAuthenticationToken(user.id!!)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authToken
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}

What it does:

Gets some data from a header
Uses it to authenticate a user by placing an auth object into the security context

What is the problem:
I've noted that if spring throws an exception (for example no row found in DB) then it is not mapped to 500 response code as usually, but to 403
Question:
How do I change my filter so that Spring does not map arbitrary unhandled exceptions to 403, but rather map them to 500
Here is my SecurityConfig
package com.fnot.backend.config.spring.security

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val telegramAuthenticationFilter: TelegramAuthenticationFilter
) {
    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .cors {  } // Enable CORS
            .authorizeHttpRequests { auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .addFilterBefore(telegramAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsFilter(): CorsFilter {
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        val config = CorsConfiguration()

        config.allowCredentials = true
        config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*") // Allow all origins
        config.addAllowedHeader("*") // Allow all headers
        config.addAllowedMethod("*") // Allow all methods

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        return CorsFilter(source)
    }
}

I've tried debugging the ExceptionTranslationFilter and it first catches the exception as a ServletException with the underlying business logic exception as cause (something like row in DB not found), but then as it processes further it gets an AccessDeniedExceptionThrown from AuthorizationFilter doFilterMethod()

Here's the solution. Its like a really unexpected new feature of spring security 6 or something. Would have been INSANLE hard to figure it out myself.
Spring: REST exceptions are caught as 403 Forbidden exception

it is not insanely hard, all you need to do is to enable debug logging and read the logs were it says that /error is being protected. And to understand why /error even exists, is written as the first thing in the spring boot error handing chapter https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/web/servlet.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling . I can agree Its insanely hard if one does not read documentation.
